# Flexbox колонки с одинаковыми отступами

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div
```

СSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: 20px
}
```

Когда не указываешь flex-wrap, то браузер подстраивает ширину элементов и задает им фиксированные отступы. Мне нужно такое же поведение с flex-wrap 
Чтобы колонки тянулись, при этом у них был фиксированный отступ, при этом они еще и переносились правильно(2 колонки в строке)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для установки ширины колонки используйте функцию [calc()](https://webref.ru/css/value/calc):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 2);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Поддержку браузерами можно увидеть на [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc()).

**UPDATE** с учетом комментария про `calc()`.

Несколько костыльный получился вариант, но работает так, как вам и нужно:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.col:nth-child(2n-1) {
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.col:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не подходит, нужна поддержка андроида 4

Comment: @ruslik тогда только на js

Comment: )))) вы серьезно? Это же flexbox

Comment: @ruslik следовательно, на flexbox можно все что угодно?

Comment: ну вроде задача то тривиальная. а Решения нормального нету.

Comment: @ruslik обновил ответ без calc